# MFMailComposeViewController's delegate not handling the 'Cancel' button or iOS 4.x and earlier

Tags: ios, delegates, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I've implemented standard mail functionality in my app according to the code sample provided by Apple.
My code is as follows

```
- (IBAction)mailBtnPressed:(id)sender
{
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail])
{
    mailer = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];

    [mailer setDelegate:self];

    [mailer setSubject:@"Een berichtje via de iPhone app"];         mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"studio@vrtfm.be", nil];
    [mailer setToRecipients:toRecipients];

    NSString *emailBody = @"";
    [mailer setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];

    [self presentModalViewController:mailer animated:YES];
}
else
{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Oeps..."
                                                    message:@"Dit toestel ondersteunt geen mail functionaliteit."
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                          otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

}

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error 
{   
    switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Mail cancelled: you cancelled the operation and no email message was queued.");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            NSLog(@"Mail saved: you saved the email message in the drafts folder.");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            NSLog(@"Mail send: the email message is queued in the outbox. It is ready to send.");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"Mail failed: the email message was not saved or queued, possibly due to an error.");
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"Mail not sent.");
            break;
    }
        [self becomeFirstResponder];
    // Remove the mail view
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Hitting the Send button invokes the delegate and it all works fine. However, hitting the Cancel button doesn't call the delegate and it just dims the view; the app hangs right there.

**Notes:**
  I am not showing the StatusBar in My App.

I am not using a xib, but the code `[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];`

This Mail functionality is working fine with iOS5, iOS5.1.  But facing the issue in lower versions only.

I have also tried using `[mailer setMailComposeDelegate:self];`

My current class xib has of size (280,480).

I am using several views in a single view which contains a scrollView of content size (1540,960).

Showing the views with the method `[scrollView scrollRectToVisible:frame animated:YES];`

Answer (score 3):

Try see at this [example](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/MailComposer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008865-Intro-DontLinkElementID_2)

short answer:

try change code line

```
[mailer setDelegate:self];
```

to

```
mailer.mailComposeDelegate = self;
```

Comment: but it won't work for me. Still i am facing the same issue for below versions of ios5

Comment: I am facing the same problem Vishnu. Did you find an answer?

Comment: @VishnuVardhanDevineni Try see a example

Comment: @JohnGoodstadt Try see a example